# NoSuchElementException on non empty list

Tags: java, list, exception

I have a runnable created this way:

```
private Runnable _animationScriptRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (AnimationManager.this) {
            while (!_stopRunning && !_animationScriptStack.isEmpty()) {
                Class key = _animationScriptStack.removeFirst();
                if (isAnimationExist(key) && isAnimationActivated(key)) {
                    AAnimation animation = _animationsClassTable.get(key);
                    animation.doBeforeAnimation();
                    animation.onAnimationBeginning();
                    do {
                        animation.onAnimation();
                    } while (isAnimationActivated(key) && animation.isAnimationRecurent() && !_stopRunning);
                    animation.onAnimationEnding();
                    animation.doAfterAnimation();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see, I check in a synchronized block that my stack (`_animationScriptStack`, created as a `LinkedList<Class<?>> _animationScriptStack`) is not empty, and if it's not, I remove the first element. But, sometimes, I have a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`, on the `removeFirst()` call.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Do you have more than one thread operating on the same collection?  Because you've got a race condition between the isEmpty and the removeFirst.

Comment: Considering that `LinkedList` only throws `NoSuchElementException` if the list is empty, I'd say that your assumption in your question is wrong. You have a concurrency issue for sure.

Comment: Side note: why is your entire loop `synchronized`?

Comment: @oldrinb It's not my code, but I think the previous developer ran into the issue once, put a synchronized there, and hopped it will solve the problem.

Comment: @PaulTomblin : As far as I can see, in the normal case, I should only have one thread. There is probably an issue launching it twice. I'm looking for it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is not thread safe and probably this is causing un-expected results in your code.

You need to use [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) in this case as you are trying to access a list in a Thread. Please look at it, I guess this is what you need.

Comment: It's probably *not* a good idea to spin until the queue isn't empty (or at least to spin *manually*). This seems like a classic producer-consumer problem, so I'd suggest a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) or a [`LinkedTransferQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html).